# auto complete intellij - less/css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, less

I have some problems with css auto complete on my html files.

My project is java project on spring/bootstrap. I have less file that is compiled to css later on. On my html files I don't have access to classes from less or bootstrap files. I have "webapp" folder configured correctly in project.

CSS files are in:

a) webapp\css\less\main.less

b) webapp\css\ (bootstrap, main.css main.min.css)

Is it possible to add css (class) completition to html files that are created in project?

Answer (score 0):

- It should do it out of the box for css: http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/html_css_editor.jsp?ide=idea
- for LESS however you might need to use a plugin : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7059?pr=idea
- I know LESS works out of the box with WebStorm and PHPStorm, though

If it still doesn't work, you might need to set the right file extension or associate that file with a certain interpreter

Comment: Dunno why but code completition doesn't work for me. I've less plugin installed already. How to add interpreter?

Comment: based on the extension, if it has .less, it should work once you installed the plugin and restarted your IDE

Comment: Damn still doesn't work ;<. Well I'm back to netbeans for now. I'll try later to solve it somehow. Thanks for ur reply ;).